# Get outsider value in inner class Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

Sorry guys,I'm new to kotlin, so please bear with me.

I have this code

```
 Class A :Basefragment()
    {
        ...

        override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
            val id = item.itemId

            if (id == R.id.save) {
                val thread = SimpleThread(editTitle.text.toString(), editDescription.text.toString())
                thread.start()
            }
        }

        inner class SimpleThread(title: String, description: String) : Thread() {
            override fun run() {
                var titles = title // how to use title ?
            }

        }
    }
```

In SimpleThread, how can I get the title value ? I get **unresolved references**

Comment: `title` is a constructor parameter but not a `var`/`val` parameter. You are probably getting an error that it is unused; this has nothing to do with inner classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current syntax only passes in `title` and `description` as constructor parameters, which you can use to initialize properties, or in an `init` block:

```
inner class SimpleThread(title: String, description: String) : Thread() {
    val title = title

    init {
        println(description)
    }
}
```

While you could save those values to properties as shown above, you can also add `val` or `var` to the constructor directly to create properties that take the values of the constructor parameters:

```
inner class SimpleThread(val title: String, val description: String) : Thread() { ... }
```

These saved properties can now be accessed from any function at any time, not just at construction.